# Add pagination in custom data collection magento 1.x

Tags: magento-1.9, pagination

I want to add pagination in custom data collection Magento 1.x. I found it and tried but it not working.

My table

[image]

My collection

```
public function getProductReturn(){
         $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
          ->addAttributeToSelect('sku');
          $collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
                    array('attribute'=>'return_item','eq'=>'1')
                ));
                $collection->setPage(2, 6);
          return $collection;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

->setPageSize(10) 
->setCurPage(1);

Try above. You will get first 10 products. If you set CurPage to 2, you will get next 10 products. To understand simply, setting 2 returns 11 to 20 result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for pagination

> In your Block file

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $collection = Mage::getModel('custom/collection')->getCollection();
        $this->setCollection($collection);
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();

        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'custom.pager');
        $pager->setAvailableLimit(array(5=>5,10=>10,20=>20,'all'=>'all'));
        $pager->setCollection($this->getCollection());
        $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
        $this->getCollection()->load();
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
    }
```

> In your phtml file add this line at last `<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?>`

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
<?php $collection = $this->getCollection(); ?>
<div>
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('My Custom Collection') ?></h1>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?>
<?php if($collection->getSize()): ?>
<table id="my-custom-table">
    <col width="1" />
    <col width="1" />
    <col />
    <col width="1" />
    <col width="1" />
    <col width="1" />
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('ID #') ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Title') ?></th>
            <th><span><?php echo $this->__('Created') ?></span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php $_odd = ''; ?>
        <?php foreach ($collection as $_obj): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $_obj->getCollectionId() ?></td>
                <td><span><?php echo $_obj->getTitle(); ?></span></td>
                <td><?php echo $this->formatDate($_obj->getCreatedTime()) ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('my-custom-table');</script>
<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <p><?php echo $this->__('The collection is empty.'); ?></p>
<?php endif ?>
```

[Reference](https://indiestechtips.wordpress.com/2012/11/10/magento-paging-in-custom-collection/)

**Hope it Helps.**